# Provisioning profiles do not match app's bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, maui

I work for a small team, and I was the first one to build a release of our .NET MAUI app for iOS distribution. I have a provisioning profile that I believe to be a company profile, and when I click it, I get a provisioning profile for my app. [image: Sign and Distribute page with an identity and provisioning profile selected]

I am now leaving this company, and trying to help another one of our developers create a build for the App Store. Unfortunately, he can only select the correct provisioning profile when NO signing identity is selected.[image: Sign and Distribute page with a provisioning profile]

When he selects either of his available signing identities, he loses the option to select the provisioning profile.[image: Sign and Distribute page with an identity but no provisioning profile]

We tried creating a build by just selecting the provisioning profile, but are unable to upload that to the App Store due to not having a proper signing identity.

How do we associate his identity with the app bundle/provisioning profile?

Comment: You can recheck if the `bundleID` of `provisioing file` is correct.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, the provisioning file appears to be correct, but not having a "signing identity" is causing the problem for us

Comment: Did you follow this document [Publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/?view=net-maui-8.0)?